# simple_form_for custom label_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I've a select that has to provide some decimal values (percentages) for an accounting application.
The values are like 10, 20, 22.5.
The problem is that want to display **the first two values with no decimal part, the third with it.**

In the simple_form_for [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), in the Collections section, it talks about a `label_method`, and i guess it would solve the problem. 
**Can you provide an example of usage of such a method?**

It would be enough, but for clarity my simple_form_for is something like this :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@company) do |f| %>

...

<%= f.input :percentage, :collection=>[BigDecimal(10),BigDecimal(20),BigDecimal(22.5,3)]%><br />

...
```

And here is what i get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarized, label_method allows you to define a method, which is called for each of the items in the given collection, and of which the result is used to display the item

Either you give a symbol as label method, like

```
label_method: :method_to_be_called
```

or you define the method in place, like

```
label_method: lambda { |value| calculated_label }
```

In your case, I would define the collection as

```
[ [BigDecimal(10), 0], [BigDecimal(20), 0], [BigDecimal(22.5, 3), 2] ]
```

and the label_method as

```
label_method: lambda { |value| number_with_precision(value[0], precision: value[1]) }
```

You probably also need a value_method, returning the right result to your server, something like

```
value_method: lambda { |value| value[0] }
```

Comment: I get the solution. Just correct a simple error: BigDecimal(22.5) gives the "can't omit precision for a Float", it has to be BigDecimal(22.5,3) 2) before i can accept it.

Comment: Always hard to make code correct without trying it 'life' !